# Modules not getting detected by Drupal

Tags: drupal, content-management-system

I am currently working on a CMS Website new installation of Drupal. I need to enable Metatagging in my website.

In order to do so I have installed all required modules, but somehow drupal is not detecting the those modules. Please refer below screenshot.

[image: Installed Module screenshot]

I have used this link of metatag module to download and install : https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag

Following are the version details of various components I am using,

Drupal : 7.35
PHP : 7.2
OS : Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
MySQL : Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24

Please help me with the resolution to this problem. I am open to any other way as well to get metatagging in place.

Thanks already !

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the screenshot, required dependencies are "missing". Make sure you have downloaded [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token), [Ctools](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools) and [Google Analytics](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics) modules, for Drupal 7, and extracted them under sites/all/modules folder. Then their flag should be "disabled". After this, you can install your desired modules alongside with their dependencies.

The wonder is that your "system" module is missing too!! its a Drupal core module, perhaps your Drupal installation is corrupted. Try re-extracting and overwriting Drupal core zip file.

Comment: Ok. But I have already installed Token, Ctools, still not working. Google analytics is enabled though. Will check on system module as well.

Comment: system module error is still not going, I have tried updating all modules and also updated drupal core.

Comment: I also obeserved one more thing, that drupal modules are updated very frequently which leads to incorrect functioning of site, is there a way to set alerts for this.